# How to trace what is invoked on ACPI events?

Tags: acpi

My question is not how to catch ACPI events, but how to track out what happens when one occurs.

I recently got interested in ACPI events. I wonder how to find out what script is triggered by ACPI events. If it does not trigger a script from `/etc/acpi/events/`, how to find what it triggers?

1. [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11785074/) is the output of `tree /etc/acpi/`. `acpid` is configured to execute `/etc/acpi/powerbtn` on Power Button Press, but upon inspecting the script, I find that `gnome-settings-daemon` might be managing the power button.
2. For media keys, found mapping of scan codes to key codes in `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb`. But from what I understand, udev just initializes stuff, and acpid is responsible for managing ACPI events. Also the udev configuration is overridden by something else, because I swapped the vol up and mute keys, and the change was not reflected even after a reboot.

So what about other triggers like laptop lid closing, audio jack connecting, plugging an AC power adapter etc.?

Comment: Did you find answer?